# Mi Amore? Is this correct?

Tags: grammar, translation, english-comparison

I want to know if I put "Mi Amore" on a sign for the name of a store would it be understood as My Love by most languages although it may be incorrect? I understand that there is a proper way to say it but would it be grossly bad grammar for a Spanish, Italian, etc. diner?  What other ways can I write it?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Have you tried looking in a dictionary before asking? And what would be the context (is it a salutation, an epithet, something else?)

Comment: Since it is none of those languages, every speaker of one of them would think: “Hell, they didn't even bother to get two words correct!” So, if I were you, I'd decide which language I want  name in, and get it correct.

Comment: @ DaG it was a concept and thanks to se I will not go forward with it. Thank y'all so much.

Comment: This question seems unclear to me unless details about context are added, as it has been required on comments, and without any utility for other users. In addition, it seems to me that it shows no research at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct translation depends, unsurprisingly, from context. The following is a rough set of indications, with the caveat that there no absolute rules, just guidelines

- If you want to use it as an epithet (e.g. "I miss you, my love, and I cannot bear to be apart from you") the correct translation is **Amore mio**
- If you want to use it as a noun (e.g. "My love for you has never dimmed"), then I would use **Il mio amore** (note the presence of the article in front and the different order of the words)

*Mi Amore* is not correct Italian. It sounds like some weird mix of Italian and Spanish to me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89289/discussion-on-answer-by-denis-nardin-mi-amore-is-this-correct).